# res.write() in Azure app service does not work for successive upload progress

Tags: node.js, express, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service, multiparty

I have code the uploads file (1.2 GB size) and I need to know the progress of the upload. I am using multiparty module in node js for multipart file.
The module has certain events such as 'progress', 'part' and so on through which I can track the file upload and process.
on localhost the following code works perfectly fine and provides the console.log() and res.write() for every chunk is uploaded, but when I host the application in Azure Web App service and see the logs the console.log() stops at just random line and after certain time it says the request is aborted.

As the document in node js says in [https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback][1] : "This sends a chunk of the response body. This method may be called multiple times to provide successive parts of the body."

I assume I can call the res.write() multiple times which will send the buffered informatio to client (which is working the way I want it on localhost but on the Azure app service) 
NOTE: I am changing the timeout limits of the req in the progress so that it will not timeout the upload.

```
form.on('progress' , function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
     console.log('Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: ' + bytesReceived)  
     res.write('Processed bytes ' + bytesReceived + '\n')
     timeOutMilliSecond += 60000
     req.setTimeout(timeOutMilliSecond)
     res.setTimeout(timeOutMilliSecond)

  })
  form.on('field', (name,value) => {
     containerName = value
  })
  form.on('part' , function(dataPart) {
     if(dataPart.filename){
        try{
           blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName, dataPart.filename, dataPart, dataPart.byteCount, function(error, response){

              if(error){
                 console.log(error)
                 res.end(error)
              }
              console.log("Uploaded")
              res.end('Blob successfully uploaded')

           })
        }catch(err){
           console.log("Error occurred in processing the part " + err)
        }

     }


     dataPart.on('error' , (err) => {
        console.log('Error in data procesing ')
     })
  })
  form.on('close' ,() => {
     console.log('Form closed')

  })
  form.on('abort', () => {
     console.log('Request aborted')
  })
  form.on('error', (err) => {
     console.log('Form processing error ')
  })

  form.parse(req)
```

on localhost it looks like this:

```
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16317362
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16382898
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16448434
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16513970
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16579506
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16645042
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16710578
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16776114
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16841650
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16907186
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16972722
Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 16998316
Uploaded
Form closed
```

but on the Azure it looks like this

```
0|index  | Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 1280013
0|index  | Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 1345549
0|index  | Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 1411085
0|index  | Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 1476621
0|index  | Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 1542157
0|index  | Upload is in progress... Processed bytes: 1558541
0|index  | Error in data procesing
0|index  | Error: Request aborted
0|index  |     at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:190:17)
0|index  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:13)
0|index  |     at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:450:9)
0|index  |     at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:443:3)
0|index  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
0|index  |     at TCP._handle.close (net.js:607:12)
0|index  | Form processing error
0|index  | Error: Request aborted
0|index  |     at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (/node_modules/multiparty/index.js:190:17)
0|index  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:13)
0|index  |     at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:450:9)
0|index  |     at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:443:3)
0|index  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
0|index  |     at TCP._handle.close (net.js:607:12)
```

But the funny thing is when I remove the line res.write() and deploy this in Azure it handles the upload perfectly fine just I dont get the successive upload responses.